# How to identify the difference of columns in two files which are in different folders using R?

Tags: r, lapply

one of the folders named "a" contains the list of files each of the files have the following column
|chr_pos|
|-------|
| 176   |
| 236   |

another folder named "b" contains the list of files each of the files has the chr_pos column.
Could anyone please explain how to compare and identify differences among each of the files in R?

Comment: That's a task where `R` doesn't shine. In a shell (zsh, bash) do `for i in a/*;do for j in b/*;do echo $i" "$j; diff $i $j ;done ;done`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question but below a solution in R  to test whether two arbitrary files are different.

```
library(tools)

    md5sum("file_1.txt") == md5sum("file_2.txt")
```

or

```
library(diffr)

diffr(filename1, filename2)
```